# Getting proper Mesh equations

Tags: circuit-analysis

Here is the circuit I need to solve.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fytrsZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My equations are as follows:

$$Vs_1+8(R_1 +R_3)=0 \\ Vs_2+12I_2-12I_3=0 \\ -28+26I_3+12(I_3-I_2)+8(I_3+I_1)=0$$

Which gives: $$ Vs_1=-71.384 \\ Vs_2=-60.923 \\I_3=2.923 $$

However these numbers don't make sense. When adding unkowns to equations such as Vs_1 and Vs_2, do you assume they're always positive, or should the have been assigned polarities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no assigned polarity here, so you have choose to one. Generally it is reasonable to choose the voltage drop across a current source to be in the different direction as its current, because normally it tends to deliver power, not use it. For example: \$V_{s1}=V_A-V_D |_{V_D=0}=V_A\$ and \$V_{s2}=V_A-V_B\$.

I assume your first equation was meant to be \$V_{s1}+8(I_1+I_3)=0\$. With my notation (it's a bit more practical, given that \$V_D\$ is ground), it becomes $$1) -V_{s1}+8(I_1+I_3)=0$$

Likewise, your second equation becomes $$2) -V_{s2}+12(I_2-I_3)=0$$

The third and last one has a small mistake, the correct form is: $$3) -28+6I_3+12(I_3-I_2)+8(I_3+I_1)=0$$

You should recalculate the currents and that will help you get the correct voltage values as well.